# botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the CreateBucket operation: Access Denied

Tags: aws-lambda, web-deployment, zappa, python-zappa

I am trying to deploy my Django project on AWS lambda using `Zappa`. Here is my `zappa_settings.json`:

```
    {
    "dev": {
        "aws_region": "us-west-2",
        "django_settings": "<project_name>.settings",
        "profile_name": "zappa",
        "project_name": "<project_name>",
        "runtime": "python3.6",
        "s3_bucket": "<s3_bucket_name>",
        "timeout_seconds": 900,  // defaults is 30 seconds
        "manage_roles": false,
        "role_name": "ZappaDjangoRole",
        "role_arn": "arn:aws:iam::<account_id>:role/ZappaDjangoRole",
        "slim_handler": true
    }
}
```

I get the error

```
"botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the CreateBucket operation: Access Denied"
```

Any idea what is causing it and how to fix this? My understanding is that Zappa zips the entire project and wants to upload it to AWS S3 bucket, but it is missing a permission when calling the CreateBucket operation. I do not understand where this permission should go.

Inside the IAM, I have created `ZappaGroup` which has permissions using `ZappaUserGeneralPolicy` and `ZappaUserS3Policy`:

my `ZappaUserGeneralPolicy`:

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
    "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Action": [
        "lambda:CreateFunction",
        "s3:ListAccessPointsForObjectLambda",
        "s3:GetAccessPoint",
        "lambda:ListVersionsByFunction",
        "logs:DescribeLogStreams",
        "route53:GetHostedZone",
        "events:PutRule",
        "s3:PutStorageLensConfiguration",
        "cloudformation:DescribeStackResource",
        "lambda:GetFunctionConfiguration",
        "iam:PutRolePolicy",
        "apigateway:DELETE",
        "events:ListRuleNamesByTarget",
        "apigateway:PATCH",
        "cloudformation:UpdateStack",
        "events:ListRules",
        "lambda:DeleteFunction",
        "events:RemoveTargets",
        "logs:FilterLogEvents",
        "apigateway:GET",
        "events:ListTargetsByRule",
        "cloudformation:ListStackResources",
        "iam:GetRole",
        "events:DescribeRule",
        "s3:PutAccountPublicAccessBlock",
        "s3:ListAccessPoints",
        "apigateway:PUT",
        "lambda:GetFunction",
        "s3:ListJobs",
        "route53:ListHostedZones",
        "route53:ChangeResourceRecordSets",
        "cloudformation:DescribeStacks",
        "s3:ListStorageLensConfigurations",
        "lambda:UpdateFunctionCode",
        "events:DeleteRule",
        "events:PutTargets",
        "s3:GetAccountPublicAccessBlock",
        "lambda:AddPermission",
        "s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
        "cloudformation:CreateStack",
        "cloudformation:DeleteStack",
        "lambda:*",
        "s3:CreateJob",
        "apigateway:POST"
    ],
    "Resource": "*"
    },
    {
    "Sid": "VisualEditor1",
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Action": [
        "iam:PassRole",
        "s3:*"
    ],
    "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::<s3_bucket from zappa_settings.json>",
        "arn:aws:iam::<account_id>:role/ZappaDjangoRole"
    ]z
    }
]
}
```

Also, my `ZappaUserS3Policy`

```
    {
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Action": [
        "s3:ListBucket"
    ],
    "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::<s3_bucket from zappa_settings.json>"
    ]
    },
    {
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Action": [
        "s3:DeleteObject",
        "s3:GetObject",
        "s3:PutObject",
        "s3:AbortMultipartUpload",
        "s3:ListMultipartUploadParts",
        "s3:ListBucketMultipartUploads"
    ],
    "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::<s3_bucket from zappa_settings.json>/*"
    ]
    }
]
}
```

And, my ZappaDjangoRole's Trust relationships:

```
   {
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
    "Sid": "",
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Principal": {
        "Service": [
        "events.amazonaws.com",
        "apigateway.amazonaws.com",
        "lambda.amazonaws.com"
        ]
    },
    "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
]
}
```

And, finally, here is my `ZappaRolePolicy`:

```
    {
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "logs:*"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:logs:*:*:*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "lambda:GetFunctionConfiguration",
                "lambda:UpdateFunctionConfiguration",
                "lambda:InvokeFunction"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "xray:PutTraceSegments",
                "xray:PutTelemetryRecords"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:AttachNetworkInterface",
                "ec2:CreateNetworkInterface",
                "ec2:DeleteNetworkInterface",
                "ec2:DescribeInstances",
                "ec2:DescribeSecurityGroups",
                "ec2:DescribeNetworkInterfaces",
                "ec2:DetachNetworkInterface",
                "ec2:ModifyNetworkInterfaceAttribute",
                "ec2:ResetNetworkInterfaceAttribute"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:*"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "kinesis:*"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:kinesis:*:*:*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "sns:*"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:sns:*:*:*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "sqs:*"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:sqs:*:*:*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "dynamodb:*"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:dynamodb:*:*:*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "route53:*"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: You could just create the `"s3_bucket": "<s3_bucket_name>",` yourself without needing to update the permissions in ZappaUserGeneralPolicy

Comment: I did, but it did not work because for some reason Zappa either wants to create its own bucket or just want to have the permission set. I know it has to do with permissions, so I am trying to give Admin priviledges to Zappa to see if that does the trick

Comment: The example policy has full "s3:*" permissions but there is a typo 4th line up from `ZappaUserGeneralPolicy`
Does a managed role work in zappa_settings with 
`"extra_permissions": [{"Effect": "Allow","Action": ["s3:*"],"Resource": "*"}]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got around this by adding the following permissions to the group my user belongs to:

```
IAMFullAccess
AmazonS3FullAccess
AdministratorAccess
```

My user also has `AdministratorAccess` permission.  Looking around, I noticed all dev-ops people are complaining about similar issues and recommending giving full admin access to the user.

Answer (score 0):

I also got the similar error message, in my case it's i gave s3 bucket name by myself, instead of using suggested default name.